# Why setBaseSectionPaint doesn't work?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a pie chart. I need fill all section same color. In jfreechart guide, i found method `setBaseSectionPaint`, but it's didn't work. I used method `setSectionPaint` in cycle, but it's not right(excess program code). Why setBaseSectionPaint doesn't work?

```
private  JFreeChart createPieChart(PieDataset piedataset){
    JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Select the desired dictionary:", piedataset,true, true, false);

    PiePlot pieplot = (PiePlot) jfreechart.getPlot();


    for (int i=0;i<piedataset.getItemCount();i++){  //excess program code
        pieplot.setSectionPaint(piedataset.getKey(i),new Color(54, 95, 196));
    }

    pieplot.setBaseSectionPaint(new Color(54, 95, 196)); //doesn't work
    return jfreechart;
}
```

Comment: http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22098

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`PiePlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PiePlot.html) method `drawItem()`, among others, invokes `lookupSectionPaint()`, which explains the algorithm used:

- if `getSectionPaint()` is non-null, return it;
- if `getSectionPaint(int)` is non-null return it;
- if `getSectionPaint(int)` is null but `autoPopulate` is `true`, attempt to fetch a new paint from the drawing supplier (`Plot.getDrawingSupplier()`);
- if all else fails, return `getBaseSectionPaint()`.

Instead, try this approach, illustrated using `org.jfree.chart.demo.PieChartDemo1` after omitting calls to `setSectionPaint()`:

```
//plot.setSectionPaint(…);
plot.setAutoPopulateSectionPaint(false);
plot.setBaseSectionPaint(Color.blue);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I need. Thank you very much!